# YahooFinanceApi nuget package - "Failure to create client"

Tags: c#, yahoo-finance

## Context

The [YahooFinanceApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YahooFinanceApi/) used to work fine at least as of a few months ago.

Here's a short program which demonstrates the issue:

```
using YahooFinanceApi;

var data = Yahoo.GetHistoricalAsync("MSFT", new DateTime(2021, 1, 1), DateTime.Now).Result;
```

Here's the result of running that program:

```
Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Failure to create client.)
 ---> System.Exception: Failure to create client.
   at YahooFinanceApi.YahooClientFactory.CreateClientAsync(CancellationToken token)
   at YahooFinanceApi.YahooClientFactory.GetClientAndCrumbAsync(Boolean reset, CancellationToken token)
   at YahooFinanceApi.Yahoo.GetResponseStreamAsync(String symbol, Nullable`1 startTime, Nullable`1 endTime, Period period, String events, CancellationToken token)
   at YahooFinanceApi.Yahoo.GetTicksAsync[ITick](String symbol, Nullable`1 startTime, Nullable`1 endTime, Period period, ShowOption showOption, Func`2 instanceFunction, CancellationToken token)
   at YahooFinanceApi.Yahoo.GetHistoricalAsync(String symbol, Nullable`1 startTime, Nullable`1 endTime, Period period, CancellationToken token)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean waitCompletionNotification)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.get_Result()
   at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in C:\Users\dharm\Dropbox\Documents\VisualStudio\YahooFinanceApiSpx\YahooFinanceApiSpx\Program.cs:line 3
```

## Question

Any suggestions for getting the example program to work?

Answer (score 2):

## Alternative package

It looks like the [YahooQuotesApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/YahooQuotesApi/) nuget package works fine.

## Example program

This example retrieves price data and writes it to a CSV file.

```
using CsvHelper;
using NodaTime;
using System.Globalization;
using YahooQuotesApi;

var quotes = new YahooQuotesBuilder()
    .WithHistoryStartDate(Instant.FromUtc(2002, 12, 1, 0, 0))
    .Build();

var item = await quotes.GetAsync("^GSPC", HistoryFlags.PriceHistory) ?? throw new ArgumentException("Unknown symbol");

using (var writer = new StreamWriter(@"yahoo-api-out.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteRecords(item.PriceHistory.Value);
}
```

## Notes

In the following github issue for the project:

https://github.com/dshe/YahooQuotesApi/issues/4

a user had reported an issue with this project. The author then mentioned that the issue should be resolved as of version 5.1.

[image]

It seems that perhaps the API service changed in such a way that it caused the various packages to no longer work as expected.

YahooFinanceApi was last updated in 2019. YahooQuotesApi appears to be more regularly updated.